REST API for Eligible role assignment with conditions for Azure resources
I'm working on automating eligible role assignments with conditions for Azure resources via REST calls. Specifically to add condition when assigning Owner role to allow users for assigning only roles like Reader, Storage blob contributor.
In Azure portal this is possible by adding conditions under "Role assignment conditions" for Owner role but I want to automate it via REST API. Could someone please confirm if it's possible to define such conditions using API?

Initially, I generated one bearer token for service principal having "Owner" access under subscription via Postman like this:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default

Response:

To create "Owner" eligible role assignment with conditions to allow users for assigning only roles like Reader and Storage Blob Data Contributor, make use of below sample API call:
PUT https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Subscription/subscriptions/subId/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests/random_guid?api-version=2020-10-01-preview

{
  "properties": {
    "principalId": "userId",
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/subId/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635",
    "requestType": "AdminAssign",
    "scheduleInfo": {
      "startDateTime": "2024-07-28T19:29:00.91Z",
      "expiration": {
        "type": "AfterDuration",
        "endDateTime": null,
        "duration": "P365D"
      }
    },
    "condition": "((!(ActionMatches{'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write'})) OR (@Request[Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments:RoleDefinitionId] ForAnyOfAnyValues:GuidEquals {acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7, ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe})) AND ((!(ActionMatches{'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/delete'})) OR (@Resource[Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments:RoleDefinitionId] ForAnyOfAnyValues:GuidEquals {acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7, ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe}))",
    "conditionVersion": "2.0"
  }
}

Response:

When I checked the same in Portal, eligible role assignment created successfully with condition as below:

To confirm that, I clicked on View/Edit option under Condition which has Reader and Storage Blob Data Contributor roles:


Thanks @Sridevi this worked perfectly BTW where you get condition value from? I went through many documents but no luck What if I want to change the condition to allow all roles except specific roles opposite to my ask? Please suggest

Please post a new question on your new requirement with more details and share link here

Changing condition value throws {
"error": {
"code": "InvalidCreateOrUpdateRoleAssignmentRequest",
"message": "The given role assignment condition is invalid."
}
}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78815997/how-to-get-the-condition-value-for-creating-an-eligible-role-assignment-with-exc Need help
